# How could I check if a value is undefined in glsl?

Tags: null, glsl, undefined, nullptr

I have a vertex shader that essentially acts as a height map, the problem is that sometimes it will write nothing to the buffer when the output of a function is undefined. (specifically in a divide by 0 case or in a sqrt(-) case) This results in jagged edges as some of the triangles aren't rendered. Is there a way for me to check for a null or undefined value in glsl?

**EDIT:** I just need something that could do: `f(x) == undefined` or `f(x) == null`, where `f(x)` is a function outputting a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating-point division by zero does not yield "undefined". It yields positive or negative infinity (INF), and you can detect an INF value with the `isinf()` function.

But for `sqrt`, there's nothing you can do. "Undefined" is not a value; it means "anything could happen".

It is best to sanitize inputs *before* doing the computation, not afterwards.

Comment: I see, thank you for this! It's going to be very difficult to filter the inputs in my particular program, but this helped shed light on what was going on.